# Getting the current date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, current-time

How can I get the current date in MS-SQL Server 2008 R2?

The format of the column in my database is `DATETIME` and dates are stored in the following format:

```
+++++++++++++ Vrdate ++++++++++
|                             |
|   2012-11-18 00:00:00.000   |
|   2012-11-19 00:00:00.000   |
|   2013-11-18 00:00:00.000   |
|   2012-12-01 00:00:00.000   |
|   2010-10-09 00:00:00.000   |
|   2012-11-11 00:00:00.000   |
|                             |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I searched but wasn't able to find the way to get the date in this format (i.e. which has the time associated with it in `00:00:00.00`). I found `GETDATE()` function but that provides the current time along with the date as well, what I want is get the date in the following format: `CurrentDate 00:00:00.00`

How may I get this?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Returns the current date with the time part removed.

`DATETIME`s are not "stored in the following format". They are stored in a binary format.

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(8))
```

The display format in the question is independent of storage.

Formatting into a particular display format should be done by your application.

Comment: I'd add that if OP wants to get a DATETIME result with TIME part set to '00:00:00.000', then he can use `SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)`.

Comment: @KamranAhmed, in that case, I'd like to point you to [T-SQL Date and Time Function Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Refresh and try again. I made a mistake and later changed it to a proper link. Sorry for that.

Comment: @LightBulb thanks, surely going to check that :)

Answer (score 17):

As you are using SQL Server 2008, go with Martin's answer.

If you find yourself needing to do it in SQL Server 2005 where you don't have access to the `Date` column type, I'd use:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22208)