# Dynamic StartDate and Todays Date in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a Stored Procedure that takes Start Date and End Dates. So the Start Date must start from 1/1/2018. I want to make the Start Date as Dynamic- meaning when we are in 2019, the start Date will pick up 1/1/2019 and End Date is always Today's date. I appreciate for any help.

StartDate: 1/1/2018
EndDate: TodaysDate

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Show us your current code attempt.

Comment: You need to add the DBMS you're using : SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the current date in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197471/getting-the-current-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it in sql itself like this

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfYear,
   GETDATE() AS Today
```

Comment: Does `GETDATE` include time?

Comment: I think it depends a lot from the DBMS :)

Comment: No, it does not include time. But I want to hold the start date in a variable and use that variable in every startdate in the body of SP instead of using Static Date.

Comment: `No, it does not include time.` `GETDATE` **does** include time.